# How to replace all regex string in a String object?

Tags: java, regex, str-replace

For a string `str_in = "instance (\\w+\\s+){0,8}deleted";` how can I extract instance and deleted by using the replaceAll function?

I tried `str_in = str_in.replaceAll("(\\w+\\s+){0,8}", "");` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to escape the single characters so that they lose their regex nature:

```
str_in.replaceAll("\\(\\\\w\\+\\\\s\\+\\)\\{0,8\\}", "")
```

Each escaping backslash needs to be escaped for itself because of the string literal.

Answer (score 1):

If you, as your question states, really want to use `replaceAll()` instead of the (in my opinion more suitable) `replace()`, you can use the `\Q` and `\E` markers to match the string literally:

```
String str_in = "instance (\\w+\\s+){0,8}deleted";
System.out.println(str_in.replaceAll("\\Q(\\w+\\s+){0,8}\\E", ""));
```

prints

```
instance deleted
```

Comment: A reasonable and correct answer. Otherwise the regex becomes: `\\(\\\\w\\+\\\\s\\+)\\{0,8\\}`. Other answers neglect to escape the `+`

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_in.replace("(\\w+\\s+){0,8}", "");`

[replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target
>   sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence. The
>   replacement proceeds from the beginning of the string to the end, for
>   example, replacing "aa" with "b" in the string "aaa" will result in
>   "ba" rather than "ab"

[replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement

Comment: `"(\\w+\\s+){0,8}"` and `""` are not `char`.

Comment: Updated, I took wrong method description. It should be charsequence.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that `(\\w+\\s+){0,8}` is literally in the string, and you want to remove it? You will need to escape each `\` again in your replaceAll, so that they are interpreted literally, not as part of a regex, and also the `(` and `{`.